# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease' with Google Version 4.3.9 version

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics

Next issue happens when building release APK/Bundle

it happens with latest version of `'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.9'` only, it works fine with  `'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'`

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileRelease'.
> Could not create task ':app:processReleaseGoogleServices'.
   > DefaultTaskContainer#NamedDomainObjectProvider.configure(Action) on task set cannot be executed in the current context.
```

build.gradle (app):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

...
    // Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.3.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'

...
```

build.gradle (root):

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.21"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.9'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
    }
}
```

gradle plugin version:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
```

Studio version: Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1

What could be a problem?

Comment: once try to connect with different Internet Connection and recheck it may be Helpful

Comment: @NikunjParadva it's related to latest version of Google Services, works fine with previous one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Upgrade `google-services plugin` in root level `build.gradle`

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10' // change version here
```

This issue is facing in `4.3.9` version and it was fix in `4.3.10`

**Found from :-** https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#google-services_plugin_v4-3-10

Comment: Great. Though Studio doesn't yet highlight that new version 4.3.10 is available

Comment: yes, I face that many times, upgrade is available but AS not shows highlighted